# Need to change the name of a metric exposed over JMX

Tags: java, jmx, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring, mbeans

My JMX Exporter class:

```
private static final String HEALTHDOMAIN = "com.xyz.abc:ContainerName=healthcheck";   
    private final MBeanExporter exporter; 

    public void registerHelathMbean(Object healthMbean, String entity) {
                try {
                    this.exporter.registerManagedResource(healthMbean, new ObjectName(String.format("%s,entity=%s", HEALTHDOMAIN, entity)));
                }
            }
```

My metric class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedAttribute;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;

@ManagedResource()
public class MongoHealthMetric extends SimpleGauge {

    public MongoHealthMetric(double value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public void setValue(Status status) {
        super.setValue(status.equals(Status.UP) ? 0.0 : 1.0);
    }

    @Override
    @ManagedAttribute
    public Double getValue() {
        return super.getValue();
    }
}
```

When I finally export the metrics over JMX via java agent-

Metric name I get: **com_xyz_abc_healthcheck_Value{entity="mongo"}** 0.0

Metric name I want: **healthcheck{entity="mongo"}** 0.0

I've tried tweaking the HEALTHDOMAIN several times but cannot find the correct domain to get the metric name as mentioned above.